# After a MooTools JSONP request completes, storage array is empty

Tags: arrays, mootools, jsonp

```
path= devicePath + 'offset=' + offset + '&limit=20&';
var deviceRequest = new Request.JSONP({
    url: path,
    callbackKey: 'jsonp',
    log: true,

    onComplete: function(data){
       console.log('Done');
       Gallery.innerHTML = '';
       for (i=0; i<20; i++){
            devices[i]=data[i].device;
       }
       console.log(devices);
    }
}).send();
```

If I try to access `devices` after this request sends, I get 'undefined'.  But the `console.log(Devices)` code prints the recieved data correctly. I don't know where my data went.

Comment: On closer inspection of the console outputs, I also think that the code following this is trying to access `devices` before the request has been completed. Is that possible? How could I prevent it?

Comment: you use events. onComplete is the only thing that guarantees the data will be there. you need to wait for the data to be available before you run the rest of your code or you need to stub it and deal with it when it arrives eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You made a common mistake: using `onComplete` instead of `onSuccess`.

`onComplete` fires when the request completes (even if there was an error), and does NOT process the JSON.

`onSuccess` fires if the request was successful, and parses the JSON.  And finally, `onFailure` fires if there was a server error (400, 500, etc).